# Data transfer rate getting slower after 15GB for larger file transfer

Tags: java, networking, tcp, jvm, netty

I have an issue with data transfer rate when sending files larger than 15GB. I have 3 servers and one client. When sending a file from client to servers, I split a file into blocks (each block is typically 256MB) and each block is replicated on 2 server. Replication happens in pipeline method. When sending a block, each block is sliced into smaller packets (each packet is typically 128 KB), sent to the servers, and merged on the server side to be stored in hard drive. Everything is fine here. I tested the system for 5GB to 50GB files with the increment of 5GB. Average write is around 600MB/sec for all files. See below chart. Here I am comparing with HDFS.

[image]

The problem happens when reading same files from servers. Files are distributed over multiple servers. For instance I can read block1 from server1, block2 from server2, and so on. Intuitively, read must be faster than write because client reads from 3 servers in parallel. when reading files smaller than 15GB {5GB, 10GB, 15GG}, the performance is around 1.1GB/sec. The problem arises when reading files larger than 20GB {20GB, 25GB, ...., 50GB}. Performance decreases as the file size increases.

[image: Performance graph for 50GB file when reading]

The above picture shows a benchmark test for reading 50GB file. Each black dot shows an individual block reading time. As you can see, the performance starts to decrease after 60th - 70th block. Interestingly, this happens for all files larger than 15GB, slowing down right around same place (around 65th block). As the size of file increases, the slow part is dominating, and the performance is getting worse. I feel like there is some obstacle around 16GB. The only hint I see that may help is that 3 servers send blocks randomly in parallel until around 65th. So blocks' transfer are overlapping. After that, one server sends at a time in round-robin order. I can see this from the log outputs. There is still some overlapping here but not as much as before 65th block.

I am using java 1.8 for this project, and netty 4.1.8. as tcp server. 
OS is CentOS 7.
Each server has two CPU (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz ) = 40 cores
64GB RAM
10 GBit Ethernet.

I have spent lots of time and could not find the root cause of problem. 
The problem may arise from Java VM, Netty, OS, OS TCP defaults, or another reason.

Server Side BlockSenderManager

```
@Override
    public void run(){

        while(nodeManager.isRunning()){
            try
            {
                BlockRequest br = blockSenders.take();
                if(br != null){
                    executor.execute(new BlockSender( br, this));
                }

                if(wait.take())
                    System.out.println(br.getBlockId()+" Delivered");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

BlockSender at Server side:

```
    @Override
        public void run()
        {
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try
            {
                java.io.File file = new java.io.File(path+"/" + blockRequest.getBlockId());

                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                fSize = file.length();
                long rem = fSize;

                sendBlockInfo();
                int bufSize;
                if (fSize < (long) packetSize)
                    bufSize = (int) fSize;
                else
                    bufSize = packetSize;
                int read = 0, packetOrder = 1;

                byte[] data;
                if(bufSize <= rem)
                    data = new byte[bufSize];
                else
                    data = new byte[(int)rem];
                while ((read = (fis.read(data))) > 0)
                {
                    if (read < 1)
                        break;

                    BlockPacket bp = new BlockPacket();

                    bp.setRequestId(blockRequest.getRequestId());
                    bp.setBlockId(blockRequest.getBlockId());
                    bp.setData(data);
                    bp.setPacketSeqNo(packetOrder);
                    if(read < bufSize)
                    {
                        bp.setIsLastPacket(true);
                    }

                    executor.execute(new Sender(bp));

                    packetOrder++;
                    if(rem > bufSize)
                        rem = rem - bufSize;

                    if(bufSize <= rem)
                        data = new byte[bufSize];
                    else
                    {
                        data = new byte[(int)rem];
                    }
                }

                fis.close();
                executor.shutdown();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

public class Sender implements Runnable
    {
        private final BlockPacket bp;
        private final FileBlock fb;
        private DataClient dc;

        public Sender(BlockPacket bp)
        {
            this.bp = bp;
            this.fb = null;
            dc = getDataClient(requestClient);
        }

        public Sender(FileBlock fb)
        {
            this.bp = null;
            this.fb = fb;
            dc = getDataClient(requestClient);
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            if (dc != null)
            {
                if (bp != null)
                {
                    dc.send(bp);
                }
                else if (fb != null)
                {
                    dc.send(fb);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

ReceivedPacketProcessor at Client side

```
public void processBlockPacket(BlockPacket bp)
    {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bp.getData());
        try
        {
            inChannel.write(buf);  
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                aFile = new RandomAccessFile(path+"/"+fileName, "rw");
                inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
                //java.io.File f = new java.io.File(path+"/"+fileName);
                //fop = new FileOutputStream(f);
                String reqId = file.getFileID();
                currentBlockId = reqId + "_" + currentBlockSeq;
                while (true)
                {
                    BlockPacket bp = null;
                    if (numberOfBlocks > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            bp = this.blockingQueue.take();
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (bp.getBlockId().equals(currentBlockId))
                        {
                            if (currentPacket == bp.getPacketSeqNo())
                            {

                                if(fileBlocks.containsKey(currentBlockId))
                                {
                                    processBlockPacket(bp);
                                    if(currentPacket < fileBlocks.get(currentBlockId).getNoOfPackets())
                                        currentPacket++;
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (fileBlocks.get(currentBlockId).getPackets().size() < 1)
                                        {
                                            removeFileBlock(currentBlockId);
                                            currentBlockSeq++;
                                            currentBlockId = reqId + "_" + currentBlockSeq;
                                            currentPacket = 1;
                                            numberOfBlocks--;
                                        } 
                                    } 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    tempList.add(bp); 
                                }

                                for(int k =numberOfBlocks; k>0; k--)
                                {
                                    if(fileBlocks.containsKey(currentBlockId))
                                    {
                                        int pCount = fileBlocks.get(currentBlockId).getNoOfPackets();
                                        int i;
                                        for (i = currentPacket; i <= pCount; i++)
                                        {
                                            if (fileBlocks.get(currentBlockId).getPackets().containsKey(i))
                                            {
                                                processBlockPacket(fileBlocks.get(currentBlockId).getPackets().remove(i));
                                                currentPacket++;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if(i <= pCount)
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (fileBlocks.get(currentBlockId).getPackets().size()  < 1)
                                            {
                                                removeFileBlock(currentBlockId);
                                                currentBlockSeq++;
                                                currentBlockId = reqId + "_" + currentBlockSeq;
                                                currentPacket = 1;
                                                numberOfBlocks--;
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(fileBlocks.containsKey(bp.getBlockId())){
                                fileBlocks.get(bp.getBlockId()).getPackets().put(bp.getPacketSeqNo(), bp);
                            }else{
                                tempList.add(bp);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                    for(int i=0; i<tempList.size(); i++){
                        if(fileBlocks.containsKey(tempList.get(i).getBlockId())){
                            BlockPacket temp = tempList.remove(i);
                            fileBlocks.get(temp.getBlockId()).getPackets().put(temp.getPacketSeqNo(), temp); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("CLOSING FILE....");
                this.isCompleted.put(true);
                inChannel.force(true);
                inChannel.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

With -XX:+PrintGCDetails turned on, [here is a sample log](https://pastebin.com/SjZ339ed).

Any comment/help is appreciated.

Comment: I would check on JVM GC, Network bandwidth utilization, read IO on server. File system cache utilization on server.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thank you for comments. I am not touching JVM GC at all. It runs with defaults. If the network bandwidth is the problem, I think, it would be problem for files smaller 15GB, too. Reading blocks from local IO is not a bottleneck for this case. I already checked on that.

Comment: @celik I think that what Jigar was trying to say is to turn the GC logs on and see if that `might be` a problem. It's not very clear how you read these files... May be some code or the way you implemented it? `FileChannels`?

Comment: insufficient data given such a complex system.

Comment: @the8472 Too many parts involve in this process. I will try too put some code.

Comment: you need to measure where the bottleneck is. sender or receiver. cpu, ram, disk IO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the dirty page ration in memory. Since the incoming data rate is higher than the local IO flush throughput, the data is accumulated in memory. Once the max allowed dirty page ratio is reached, the receiver does not accept more data. Thus, the system is bounded with local IO, not the network in this case. So the diminishing of return happens at about 15GB. You can change some setting in

> /etc/sysctl.conf

Such as:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2
vm.dirty_ratio = 80
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
```

[This](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/) might be a useful reading.

The system performance is still bounded by local IO and max allowed dirty page ratio. You can increase increase the dirty page ratio to only postpone the diminishing of return time. It will reach again this point if the file/data is larger. New Results:
[image]